# The `bind` operator in monadic evaluation

Tags: scheme, monads

I've read a few times [the article of Dan Friedman about monadic evaluation](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c311/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=schemersviewofmonads.pdf) implemented in Scheme and I am troubled by the exercise from the end of the subchapter of `State monad`.

The article is very clear, one gains a deep understanding by doing,  minimal theory, but this exercise is really fuzzy.  I am afraid that I miss some important aspect and this is why I ask here.

The exercise is so:

> In remberevensXcountevens, the increment takes place before the tail recursive call, but we are free
>   to reorder these events. Implement this reordered-events variant by having the body of the sequel become the
>   ﬁrst argument to bind state and make the appropriate adjustments to the sequel. Is this new ﬁrst argument
>   to bind state a tail call?

It asks to call the sequel first from the `>>=` operator and after that to call the `ma` passed as an argument to bind.

I do not understand how to make the recursive call happen first, and after that to call the `ma` that changes the value of the state.  I just switched the arguments of `>>=` but not the order of evaluation.

If I try to evaluate the `sequel` first I do not know what `value` to pass.

My code is so:

```
(define return
  (lambda (a)
    (lambda (s)
      (cons a s))))

(define >>=
  (lambda (sequel ma)
    (lambda (s)
      (let ((pair (ma s)))
        (let ((value (car pair))
              (state (cdr pair)))
          (let ((mb (sequel value)))
            (mb state)))))))

(define rember/count
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? l) (return '()))
          ((list? (car l))
           (>>= (lambda (a)
                  (>>= (lambda (d)
                         (return (cons a d)))
                       (rember/count (cdr l))))
                (rember/count (car l))))
          ((even? (car l))
           (>>= (lambda (_) (rember/count (cdr l)))
                ;;  here I want to evaluate the addition AFTER the `(rember/count (cdr l))`.
                (lambda (s) (cons '_ (+ 1 s)))))
          (else
           (>>= (lambda (d)
                  (return (cons (car l) d)))
                (rember/count (cdr l)))))))

((rember/count '(1 2 3 4 (7 8 9 10 11) 5 6)) 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw function is

```
...
    (bind (λ (s) `(_ . ,(add1 s)))
                 (λ (_) (remberevensXcountevens d)))
...
```

Now, first thing to do is **have the body of the sequel**, which is (rXc d), **become the ﬁrst argument to bind**. 
So we have

```
(bind (remberevensXcountevens d)
      (λ (d) ...))
```

Note that we need d to keep the result of recursive call around.

And we know we have an even number, we gotta add1 to the state.

```
(bind (remberevensXcountevens d) 
      (λ (d) (... (λ (s) (cons '_ (add1 s))) ...)))
```

(λ (s) ...) is a monad without a pure value. We need to bind it to make it a part of our computation.
So

```
(bind (remberevensXcountevens d)
      (λ (d) (bind (λ (s) (cons '_ (add1 s))) 
                   (λ (_) ...))))
```

Now the state is updated and we have a handy pure value. It naturally follows:

```
(bind (remberevensXcountevens d)
      (λ (d) (bind (λ (s) (cons '_ (add1 s))) 
                   (λ (_) (unit d)))))
```

Comment: Dan asked me if your answer was good -- yes, it was really good, actually after I saw your answer I finally understood what Dan meant there.  Thanks.